# How do I convert Pandas object to a list in python3

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Basically I need to convert a column I got a from a csv using pandas and put it into a list.  It's currently a pandas object and I tried doing list(pandaObject) but that doesn't work.  Does anybody have any ideas?

```py
df = pandas.read_csv(csv_file)
years=df[['1987']]  #Gets a a column

###Now I need something to convert years to a list###
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`years = df[['1987']]` returns a dataframe with only that column. Instead, you should first get a Series out of the column and then convert to a list:

```
years = df['1987'] #return a Series
years_list = years.tolist() #coverts Series to list
```

Comment: This can be done in one step. years_list = df['1987'].tolist()